# Как добавить анимацию в QProgressBar?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, анимация, qprogressbar

Я долго искала пример любой анимации `QProgressBar`, но мне не удалось ничего найти. По умолчанию в нём есть анимация переливания более светлой размытой зелёной полоски:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при изменении `StyleSheet` она пропадает. Мне удалось найти только стили с `qlineargradient` и изменение цветов в зависимости от прогресса, но это не то, как сделать статичную анимацию как в прогресс баре по умолчанию или любую другую, просто чтоб было видно, что идёт загрузка.

Минимальный воспроизводимый пример с `QProgressBar` и установленным `StyleSheet`:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer

STYLE = '''QProgressBar {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    border: solid grey;
    border-radius: 15px;
    color: white;
}

QProgressBar::chunk {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 1, y2: 1,stop: 0 white, stop: 0.4 gray,stop: 1 green);
    border-radius :15px;
}   '''

count = 0

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("ProgressBar widget")
        self.setGeometry(350, 150, 500, 500)
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.progressBar = QProgressBar()
        btnStart = QPushButton("Start")
        btnStart.clicked.connect(self.timerStart)
        btnStop = QPushButton("Stop")
        btnStop.clicked.connect(self.timerStop)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(100)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.runProgressBar)
        vbox.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        hbox.addWidget(btnStart)
        hbox.addWidget(btnStop)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.progressBar.setFixedHeight(30)
        self.progressBar.setStyleSheet(STYLE)

        self.show()

    def runProgressBar(self):
        global count
        count += 1
        print(count)
        self.progressBar.setValue(count)
        if count == 100:
            self.timer.stop()

    def timerStart(self):
        self.timer.start()

    def timerStop(self):
        self.timer.stop()


def main():
    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from styleAnimation import QProgressStyleAnimation


class ColourfulProgress(QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._color = kwargs.pop('color', QColor(43, 194, 83))
        self._fps = kwargs.pop('fps', 60)
        self._lineWidth = kwargs.pop('lineWidth', 50)
        self._radius = kwargs.pop('radius', None)
        self._animation = None
        super(ColourfulProgress, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setColor(self._color)
        self.setFps(self._fps)
        self.setLineWidth(self._lineWidth)
        self.setRadius(self._radius)

    def setColor(self, color):
        self._color = QColor(color) if isinstance(
            color, (QColor, Qt.GlobalColor)) else QColor(43, 194, 83)

    def setFps(self, fps):
        self._fps = max(int(fps), 1) if isinstance(fps, (int, float)) else 60

    def setLineWidth(self, width):
        self._lineWidth = max(int(width), 0) if isinstance(width, (int, float)) else 50

    def setRadius(self, radius):
        self._radius = max(int(radius), 1) if isinstance(radius, (int, float)) else None

    def paintEvent(self, _):
        option = QStyleOptionProgressBar()
        self.initStyleOption(option)

        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.translate(0.5, 0.5)

        vertical = option.orientation == Qt.Vertical
        inverted = option.invertedAppearance  
        indeterminate = (option.minimum == option.maximum) or (
            option.minimum < option.progress < option.maximum)
        rect = option.rect

        if vertical:
            rect = QRect(rect.left(), rect.top(), rect.height(), rect.width())                          
            m = QTransform.fromTranslate(rect.height(), 0)
            m.rotate(90.0)
            painter.setTransform(m, True)

        maxWidth = rect.width()
        progress = max(option.progress, option.minimum)
        totalSteps = max(1, option.maximum - option.minimum)
        progressSteps = progress - option.minimum
        progressBarWidth = int(progressSteps * maxWidth / totalSteps)
        width = progressBarWidth 
        
        radius = max(1, (min(width,
                             self.width() if vertical else self.height()) //
                         4) if self._radius is None else self._radius)

        reverse = (not vertical and
                   option.direction == Qt.RightToLeft) or vertical
        if inverted:
            reverse = not reverse

        path = QPainterPath()
        if not reverse:
            progressBar = QRectF(rect.left(), rect.top(), width, rect.height())
        else:
            progressBar = QRectF(rect.right() - width, rect.top(), width,
                                 rect.height())

        path.addRoundedRect(progressBar, radius, radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)

        painter.setPen(Qt.NoPen)
        painter.setBrush(self._color)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(progressBar, radius, radius)

        if not indeterminate:
            if self._animation:
                self._animation.stop()
                self._animation = None
        else:
            color = self._color.lighter(320)
            color.setAlpha(80)
            painter.setPen(QPen(color, self._lineWidth))

            if self._animation:
                step = int(self._animation.animationStep() % self._lineWidth)
            else:
                step = 0
                self._animation = QProgressStyleAnimation(self._fps, self)
                self._animation.start()

            startX = int(progressBar.left() - rect.height() - self._lineWidth)
            endX = int(rect.right() + self._lineWidth)

            if (not inverted and not vertical) or (inverted and vertical):
                lines = [
                    QLineF(x + step, progressBar.bottom(),
                           x + rect.height() + step, progressBar.top())
                    for x in range(startX, endX, self._lineWidth)
                ]
            else:
                lines = [
                    QLineF(x - step, progressBar.bottom(),
                           x + rect.height() - step, progressBar.top())
                    for x in range(startX, endX, self._lineWidth)
                ]
            painter.drawLines(lines)

        painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.red, 5, Qt.SolidLine))
        painter.setFont(QFont('Decorative', 15))
        painter.drawText(0, 0, width, 30, Qt.AlignCenter, str(option.progress) )
            

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("ProgressBar widget")

        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        
        self.progressBar = ColourfulProgress(color=QColor('#85c440'))  
        self.progressBar.setMinimumWidth(500)
        self.progressBar.setRange(0, 100)
        self.progressBar.setFixedHeight(30)
        
        layout.addWidget(self.progressBar, 0, 0, 1, 2)
        
        self.count = 0                                                        
        self.fl = False                                                        
        
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(150)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.runProgressBar)
        
        btnStart = QPushButton("Start")
        btnStart.clicked.connect(self.timerStart)
        btnStop = QPushButton("Stop")
        btnStop.clicked.connect(self.timerStop)
        layout.addWidget(btnStart, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        layout.addWidget(btnStop, 2, 1, 1, 1)

    def runProgressBar(self):
        if not self.fl:
            self.count += 1

        if self.count > 5 and not self.fl:
            self.progressBar.setValue(self.count)
            
        if self.count == 100:
            self.timer.stop()

    def timerStart(self):
        if self.count == 100:
            self.count = 0
        self.fl = False   
        self.timer.start()

    def timerStop(self):
        self.fl = True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**styleAnimation.py**

```
from enum import IntEnum
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QAbstractAnimation, QCoreApplication, 
    QEvent, QTime)

ScrollBarFadeOutDuration = 200.0
ScrollBarFadeOutDelay = 450.0
StyleAnimationUpdate = 213


class QStyleAnimation(QAbstractAnimation):
    FrameRate = IntEnum(
        'FrameRate',
        ['DefaultFps', 'SixtyFps', 'ThirtyFps', 'TwentyFps', 'FifteenFps'])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QStyleAnimation, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._delay = 0
        self._duration = -1
        self._startTime = QTime.currentTime()
        self._fps = self.FrameRate.ThirtyFps
        self._skip = 0

    def target(self):
        return self.parent()

    def duration(self):
        return self._duration

    def setDuration(self, duration):
        self._duration = duration

    def delay(self):
        return self._delay

    def setDelay(self, delay):
        self._delay = delay

    def startTime(self):
        return self._startTime

    def setStartTime(self, time):
        self._startTime = time

    def frameRate(self):
        return self._fps

    def setFrameRate(self, fps):
        self._fps = fps

    def updateTarget(self):
        event = QEvent(QEvent.Type(StyleAnimationUpdate))
        event.setAccepted(False)
        QCoreApplication.sendEvent(self.target(), event)
        if not event.isAccepted():
            self.stop()

    def start(self):
        self._skip = 0
        super(QStyleAnimation, self).start(QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

    def isUpdateNeeded(self):
        return self.currentTime() > self._delay

    def updateCurrentTime(self, _):
        self._skip += 1
        if self._skip >= self._fps:
            self._skip = 0
            if self.parent() and self.isUpdateNeeded():
                self.updateTarget()


class QProgressStyleAnimation(QStyleAnimation):
    def __init__(self, speed, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QProgressStyleAnimation, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._speed = speed
        self._step = -1

    def animationStep(self):
        return self.currentTime() / (1000.0 / self._speed)

    def progressStep(self, width):
        step = self.animationStep()
        progress = (step * width / self._speed) % width
        if (((step * width / self._speed) % (2 * width)) >= width):
            progress = width - progress
        return progress

    def speed(self):
        return self._speed

    def setSpeed(self, speed):
        self._speed = speed

    def isUpdateNeeded(self):
        if super(QProgressStyleAnimation, self).isUpdateNeeded():
            current = self.animationStep()
            if self._step == -1 or self._step != current:
                self._step = current
                return True
        return False
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer


# - count = 0

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("ProgressBar widget")
        self.setGeometry(350, 150, 500, 500)
        
        self.count = 0                                                              # +++
        self.UI()

    def UI(self):
        vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        hbox = QHBoxLayout()
        self.progressBar = QProgressBar()
        btnStart = QPushButton("Start")
        btnStart.clicked.connect(self.timerStart)
        btnStop = QPushButton("Stop")
        btnStop.clicked.connect(self.timerStop)
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.setInterval(100)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.runProgressBar)
        vbox.addWidget(self.progressBar)
        vbox.addLayout(hbox)
        hbox.addWidget(btnStart)
        hbox.addWidget(btnStop)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

        self.progressBar.setFixedHeight(30)

    def runProgressBar(self):
#        global count
        self.count += 1
        print(self.count)
        if self.count > 5:
            self.progressBar.setValue(self.count)
        if self.count == 100:
            self.timer.stop()

    def timerStart(self):
        if self.count == 100:
            self.count = 0
        self.timer.start()

    def timerStop(self):
        self.timer.stop()


STYLE = '''
QProgressBar {
    background-color: rgb(98, 114, 164);
    color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px;
}
QProgressBar::chunk {
    border-radius: 14px;
    background-color: qlineargradient(
        spread:pad, x1:0, y1:0.511364, x2:1, y2:0.523, 
        stop:0 rgba(254, 121, 199, 255), 
        stop:1 rgba(170, 85, 255, 255));
}   
'''

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(STYLE)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а при остановке никакая анимация не происходит? в стандартном прогресс баре бегает вот эта светло зелёная полоска: https://fex.net/ru/s/e3yvdbc, я про неё говорила в вопросе.

Comment: @Афродита, лично у меня,  в стандартном прогресс баре  НЕ БЕГАЕТ светло зелёная полоска. Но я понял вашу задумку и предложу вам возможный вариант, но это будет в другом ответе.

Comment: ну это как пример, суть в том, чтобы как-то показать движение, потому что без него ощущение что программа просто зависла (если происходит долгая обработка и прогресс бар стоит на месте). Буду ждать вариант, спасибо!